# How to restrict the download of all files in a folder?

Tags: links, pdf, download

I have several `.pdf` files, which should be viewed on my website by clicking a link on a page. But when a pdf file opens, in the address bar the directory where all .pdf files reside is visible. So if the user enters `http://example.com/myDir` in the address bar he will see and be able to download all files at once. But I don't want that!

When I `chmod 644 myDir`, the files are not visible even for my site - i.e. you can not open them by clicking the link I have mentioned. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Using .htaccess you can block it like this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

If you want to prevent users from being able to access those files without first being authenticated see [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/permissions-for-serving-up-temporary-files/2635#2635).

Answer (score 2):

You should disallow directory browsing. There are a few ways you could to that, depending upon what sort of access you have to the server, but [using htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/disable-directory-listings/) is the simplest.

For example, to prevent all PDF files from being listed:

```
IndexIgnore *.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty file named `index.html` in your `myDir` folder. Anyone visiting that folder will then see a blank screen instead of a directory listing.