# How to make upload images harder to access from url?

Tags: google, facebook, images, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restrict the download of all files in a folder?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/how-to-restrict-the-download-of-all-files-in-a-folder)

I am wondering how Facebook, Google+, Twitter and so on prevent images users upload, from being navigated like: http://interactionhero.com/images/ ....

I have an application where users upload there folder /profile (chmod 777), and if I go to www.____.com/profile , all the images are accessible. Is there a way I can prevent this or improve it?

Comment: The main difference is that that question deals with files the web-master uploaded himself, on my case the folders has 777 permission and anyone can upload a profile image. Not sure if that fact makes the situation different or the same, that is what hopefully I can find out.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference how the files got there, you can use the same method to stop listing the images.